# Como ejecutar una vez Asynctask y utilizarla en todas las actividades?

Tags: android, android-studio, hilos, android-asynctask, asynctask

Estoy utilizando una Asynctask en el MainActivity, estoy utilizando telemetria con arduino , es decir, necesito utilizar la funcion OnProgressUpdate() para que me rellene los campos de texto que recibo del bluetooth, tengo diferentes actividades,,, La clase AsyncTask es esta

```js
package com.example.blesubb;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.Closeable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.UUID;

/**
 * Created by Roque on 4/03/14.
 */
public class MiAsyncTask extends AsyncTask <BluetoothConnection, String, Void>
{
private static final String TAG = "MiAsyncTask";

//Identificador unico universal del puerto bluetooth en android (UUID)
private static final String UUID_SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE = "00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB";
private Integer datos = 0;
private BluetoothSocket mSocket = null;
private BufferedReader mBufferedReader = null;
private MiCallback callback;
private SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
private boolean recibiendo = false;
private InputStream aStream = null;
private InputStreamReader aReader = null;
private BluetoothConnection BlueConnect;
private String aString ;
public static MiAsyncTask instancia = null;


private int contadorConexiones = 0;
    boolean ok;



    public interface MiCallback {
    void onTaskCompleted();

    void onCancelled();

    void subDatosUpdate(String p);

    void subDatos(String v);
}


    public MiAsyncTask(MiCallback CALLBACK) {
        callback = CALLBACK;

    }





    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(BluetoothConnection... devices) {

        BlueConnect=devices[0];


      //  final BluetoothDevice device = BlueConnect.getRemoteDevice();
//Realizamos la conexion al disp.blueetoth. A veces la conexion falla aunque el dispositivo
//este presente. Asi que si falla, y la tarea no ha sido cancelada, lo reintentamos.

                conectayRecibeBT();




        return null;
    }

    private boolean conectayRecibeBT() {
//Abrimos la conexión con el dispositivo.
        ok = true;

        try {
            contadorConexiones++;


            mSocket=BlueConnect.getSocket();
            aStream = mSocket.getInputStream();
            aReader = new InputStreamReader(aStream);
            mBufferedReader = new BufferedReader(aReader);

            

/*Mientras no se cancele la tarea asincrona (cuando se destruya la actividad)
se interroga al canal de comunicación por la temperatura*/

            while (!isCancelled()) {

                try {
                    System.out.println("Estoy en el hilo , leyendo la entrada del buffer");
                    aString = mBufferedReader.readLine();

                    if ((aString != null) && (!aString.isEmpty())) {

                        try {

                            //Esta funcion desencada inmediatamente otra funcion "onProgressUpdate". La cual
                            //permitira comunicarlos a traves de CallBack con el hilo PRINCIPAL
                            System.out.println(aString);
                            publishProgress(aString);


                        } catch (Exception e) {

//Si falla el formateo de los datos, no hacemos nada. Mostramos la excepción en la consola para
//observar el error.
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

//Una vez la tarea se ha cancelado, cerramos la conexión con el dispositivo bluetooth.
          //  temperatura.setInformacion("Cerrando conexion BT");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            ok = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        //    temperatura.setInformacion("Error conectando con dispositivo bt, reintento " + contadorConexiones + "... Si este error se repite, reinicie el arduino.");
            publishProgress(aString);


        }
        return ok;
    }


    private UUID getSerialPortUUID() {
        return UUID.fromString(UUID_SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE);
    }

    private void close(Closeable aConnectedObject) {
        if (aConnectedObject == null) return;
        try {
            aConnectedObject.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        aConnectedObject = null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

        System.out.println("Estoy en OnProgressUpdate");
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        callback.subDatosUpdate(values[0]);
       // callback.subDatos(values[0]);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {

        try {
            mSocket.close();
            mBufferedReader.close();
            aReader.close();
            aStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        callback.onCancelled();
    }
}
```

Desde el MainActivity llamo a este thread de la siguiente manera:

```js
   private void connectThread() {
        System.out.println("Ejecutamos el HILO en segundo plano");

        tareaAsincrona = new MiAsyncTask(this);
        tareaAsincrona.execute(BlueConn);


    }
```

Le paso como parametro a DoInBackGround la conexion bluetooth y utilizo el CALLBACK para devolverme la informacion pero solo a la actividad en la que lo he lanzado, la pregunta es:

Si yo cambio de actividad, me valdria solo con implementar MiAsyncTask y ya estaria recibiendo por la funcion callback, o  callback solo funciona para la actividad donde se ha lanzado el THREAD, si no es asi, cual seria el funcionamiento correcto??

Gracias!!!!!

Comment: No se que datos guardas del bluetooth pero el caso que propones no seria posible ya que si deblaras una nueva instancia el callback sera unicamente de esa instancia no de la que iniciaste anteriormente. Para recibir los datos en otra actividad se me ocurren 2 formas: - Una vez cambies de actividad matas el thread en progreso y lo inicias en cada actividad (creo que es la menos recomendable ya que en el lapso de tiempo perderías datos. - Otra opción sería guardar los datos que vas sacando del callback en persistencia y acceder a ellos desde otras actividades. En caso de un gran volumen de datos

Comment: Buen dia, recibo datos de un robot como accelerometro, magnetometro, datos del mando... algo que necesito ver en TIEMPO REAL, por ello en una misma actividad con layout por tamaño de pantalla, solo puedo mostrar los datos del mando por ejemplo, pero tengo que llamar a otra actividad con otro layout para mostrar los datos del accelerometro,,,, iniciar el thread en cada cambio de actividad lo he pensado pero queria saber si habia algun metodo que sea global para recuperarlo en cualquier actividad,

Comment: Para cogerlo en tiempo real lo tienes que almacenar en algún lado y compartirlo entre actividades o otra opción que se me ocurre seria ir mandado broodcast de los resultados cada vez que los recibas y los vas escuchando de todas las actividades que precises.

Comment: Tendria logica utilizar una actividad pero tener 4 diferentes layouts y cambiar el layout con setContentView??? y de esta manera siempre tendria el callback a la actividad pero podria tener todos los campos de texto al alcance sin tener que cambiar de actividad